# ObjC variadic arguments: hint terminator

Tags: objective-c, variadic, terminator

In Xcode, if I start typing "[NSArray arrayWith" I get the following hint:

```
id arrayWithObjects:(id), ..., nil
```

As you can see, the terminator is explicit.

If I write a method taking variadic arguments by myself, I get this hint

```
id myMethod:(id), ...
```

(the terminator is not shown). How can I hint the terminator I want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the

```
__attribute__((sentinel))
```

attribute to your variadic method, or alternatively, use the

```
NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION
```

macro, which expands to the same. This way, the compiler will know that your variadic argument list needs to be 0-terminated.

```
- (void)foo:(id)arg1, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, arg1);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Great. Is there a way to hint a custom terminator (I mean, something different from nil)?

Comment: @user732274 I don't think so.